# Does TreeView create a new ItemContainerGenerator per Node/Level?

Tags: wpf

I am wondering if there is one "global" generator for TreeView or does a new ItemContainerGenerator gets created on each node/level, when expanded?

Anyone who had to deal with this depth of wpf?

Thanks again in advance I appreciate your help much. :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted this question to msdn forum as well. And this is what they answered to me.

I guess I was right. Each node has its own generator.

Check it out:

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d36d164a-296e-44d5-80a6-4f09414d0a64/does-treeview-create-a-new-itemcontainergenerator-per-nodelevel?forum=wpf

Answer (score 0):

ItemContainerGenerator for any ItemsControl (including TreeView) is associated with the control and is responsible for generating the UIElement items on behalf of a ItemsControl.

ItemContainerGenerator generates each and every item, not each item creates its own ItemContainerGenerator.
But as rightly pointed out by you, treeviewitem is in itself itemscontrol so each will have its generator which will generate its child.
MSDN ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemcontainergenerator.aspx

> The ItemsControl generates its items through the
>   IItemContainerGenerator interface. The ItemContainerGenerator property
>   of the ItemsControl is of type ItemContainerGenerator, which
>   implements the IItemContainerGenerator interface.

Comment: Hi nit, nice to hear from you again. :) I think this answer is kinda confirming that a new ItemContainerGenerator is being created on each node. TreeView is an ItemsControl but so is TreeViewItem. According to that definition you posted from MSDN every ItemsControl has its own ItemContainerGenerator so basically in the end you will have a generator for each node as long node is expanded of course.

Comment: Interesting fact. :) :)

Comment: Yup each item`s generator generates its child items